# File encryption using Android dev key

Tags: android, cryptography

I need to download some files from my web server. I want to avoid that an user can download the files from this public address and use them. I can encrypt their content with a symmetric key, so I should store the key in the app. Instead, could I use in some way the android developer key? In this way only my app could decrypt the files. How can I do? Does it make any sense?

Comment: What do you mean with "android developer key"? The key used for signing the app?

Comment: Yep, is it possible?

Comment: I don't think you can access the signing key.

Comment: Maybe. However, I don't see the sense since the decryption key must be in your app anyway, one way or the other. So if someone wants to get the plain files he'll find a way.

Comment: @cygery Do you think there are other strategies?

Comment: This depends on your threat model. You can make it difficult to access the plain data, but you can't prevent it. What kind of files are these (text/media/etc.)?

Comment: I know I can't stop piracy at 100% but I want to do at least something. They are text files.

Comment: I can't think of a practical solution for this. If feasible you could require server authentication to access the files, transfer them via a SSL-encrypted connection, and store then encrypted. Still, you have the issue of storing the decryption key. Also, consider that once someone pirates your files it's basically game-over.

Comment: Encryption in Java? forget it, every monkey can decompile your source. You could hover use a simple 3KTDES in cpp and use JNI to call the cpp encrypt/decrypt methods.